# Apache cordova in visual studio 13

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, cross-platform

i have installed apache cordova tools for vs13 and now when i run my code i get error

Warning 1   Acquiring Cordova Tools. Any build cancellation requests will be processed after acquisition has completed. BlankCordovaApp2
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Software/Tool

Issue

Android SDK               The software is missing from your system. You may also have to configure it after installation. Instructions

Git CLI                    The software is missing from your system. You may also have to configure it after installation. Instructions

Apple iTunes               The software is missing from your system. You may also have to configure it after installation. Instructions

Oracle Java SDK            The software is missing from your system. You may also have to configure it after installation. Instructions

After fixing these issues, please restart Visual Studio to ensure that changes have been applied. 
this is the error which i get please help me

Answer (score 0):

Please install missing components first. See the answer below

The third-party components that Visual Studio installs for you
    Visual Studio installs these third-party components. You'll need them to use Apache Cordova, and to target the Android platform.

```
Component   Why Visual Studio installs it**
Apache Ant 1.8.0 (or later) To build Android apps.
32-bit Oracle Java JDK 7    To build Android apps.
Android SDK To build Android apps and to start the Apache Ripple simulator.
Joyent Node.js  To integrate with the Apache Cordova Command Line Interface (CLI) and the Apache Ripple simulator.
Git CLI To enable you to manually add Git URIs for specific Cordova plug-ins.
```

Comment: For more instruction visit this official site:-http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/install-vs-tools-apache-cordova/